# Counting the number of different links

Tags: netlogo

In my code all turtles own *n*-features represented by a *n*-tuple (*a*<sub>1</sub>,a<sub>2</sub>,...,*a*<sub>n</sub>). where each *a*<sub>i</sub> can take values 0 or 1. 
I have created some links between turtles. If two turtles share *k*-features (coordinate-wise matching) and there is a link between them then we call the link as *k*-link.

How can I find for each *k* (between 0 to *n*) how many *k*-links are there in total?

Comment: StackOverflow [doesn't support LaTeX](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/60020/170689). You can usually achieve something decent using markdown and unicode. I've edited your question.

Comment: Also, a mathematical description is _very_ nice, but often not quite enough: please post code when you have it; show us what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

You don't tell us much about how you have structured your code, so I'm going to assume that your *n*-tuples are implemented as lists (which would make the most sense in NetLogo).

Here is a full example:

```
turtles-own [ a ]
links-own [ k ]
globals [ n ]

to setup
  ca
  set n 5
  crt 10 [ ; create turtles with random feature lists
    set a n-values n [ random 2 ]
  ]
  ask turtles [ ; make a full network
    create-links-with other turtles
  ]
  ask links [ ; calculate k for all links
    set k k-of-feature-lists ([a] of end1) ([a] of end2)
  ]
  foreach n-values (n + 1) [ ? ] [ ; display number of k-links
    show (word ? "-links: " count links with [ k = ? ])
  ]
end

to-report k-of-feature-lists [ a1 a2 ]
  report length filter [?] (map = a1 a2)
end
```

Apart from `k-of-feature-lists`, this is fairly trivial code. What `k-of-feature-lists` does is to:

- transform two lists of features into a single list of booleans containing a `true` value if the corresponding element is equal in both feature lists and `false` if it is not. This is accomplished using [`map`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#map) and the [concise task syntax](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#tasks) for `=`;
- [`filter`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#filter) the list of booleans to keep only the `true` values;
- report the [`length`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#length) of that filtered list, which is equal to the number of features that where the same in `a1` and `a2`;

There are plenty of other ways to do that (some more efficient) but this one is nice and concise.